# Ratio of data matching / not matching target variable in training dataset in XGBoost

Tags: boosting

I have inherited an XGBoost model and training script.

The current implementation uses a training data set of data split 50 / 50 between inputs matching the target variable, and data not matching the target variable.

This doesn't mimic the actual data in our domain. which is much closer to 98 / 2 split.

Feels incorrect to me, Should my training data set match real world data ?

Comment: Do you mean that the origina l data are oversampled such that the frequencies are equal? Also, can you find (or generate) metrics of the current implementation? We do not want to change what works already! :)

Comment: Yes. It looks like the original code generates a set of data matching the target variable, then appends an equal size set of data not matching the target variable, and uses that for training. Can you point me to a reference as to how to generate those metrics?

Comment: So effectively the majority class is downsampled during training; it is an approach... You can look into standard metrics like AUCROC and Brier score for starters but note that it is relevant to calculate these using "real" instead of oversampled frequencies.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Going to modify the input set and see how it performs